# Is it possible to use basic authentication instead of oauth in FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working in Spring-boot and I wanted to know if it is possible to authenticate the firebase cloud messaging by using basic auth instead of oauth

I want to use basic authentication with no tokens or anything like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  You must follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server).

> The FCM HTTP v1 API authorizes requests with a short-lived OAuth 2.0 access token.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll need to try another way

Answer (score 1):

FCM doesn't support basic authentication, it requires the  OAuth 2.0 tokens for authentication and authorization. For that,
you can use Firebase Admin SDK, which will generate access tokens using service account credentials that you can use to authenticate with the FCM.

An example code;

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

String registrationToken = "<YOUR_DEVICE_REGISTRATION_TOKEN>";

Message message = Message.builder()
    .putData("name", "John")
    .putData("surname", "Doe")
    .setToken(registrationToken)
    .build();

String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```